# Swagger return Failed to fetch on some API

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger

I got a problem when use c# gen swagger but some of my API has return

```
|---------------------|---------------------------------|
|        Code         |             Details             |
|---------------------|---------------------------------|
|    Undocumented     |    TypeError: Failed to fetch   |
|---------------------|---------------------------------|
```

Also many APIs has return expected result (200 with proper objects result)

here is my Controller

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/Promotion")]
public class PromotionV1Controller : Controller
{
    private myDbContext _DbContext;
    public PromotionV1Controller(myDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _DbContext= dbContext;
    }

    // GET api/Promotion
    /// <summary>
    /// Get list of Promotion
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IEnumerable<Promotion> Get()
    {
        return _DbContext.Promotions.AsNoTracking().Where(x.IsActive);
    }

    // GET api/Promotion/VIP
    /// <summary>
    /// Get list of VIP Promotion
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet, Route("VIP")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IEnumerable<Promotion> Get()
    {
        return _DbContext.Promotions.AsNoTracking().Where(x.IsActive && x.Type == AdsType.VIP);
    }
}
```

in Api/V1/Promotion it return expected objects and status code, But in Api/V1/Promotion/VIP it return `Undocumented TypeError: Failed to fetch`

I'm already try to make another Controller with different name in same file and other file but other APIs with different name work fine return expected objects i can't find what is the cause of my problem

I'm already try search whole project for Promotion Keyword that i may hard-code it somewhere but nothing suspicious

edit* in chrome's browser console it show error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

and it only happen in chrome i try in Firefox everything gone well but in chrome only 1 API error another work fine and i can directly call to this API through browser only execute from swagger that got a problem

Comment: What are the error messages in the browser console?

Comment: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` happened in chrome only and i can directly call to this API through browser only call from swagger that got a problem

Comment: Do you have an ad blocker installed by any chance? Disable this and see if the problem goes away

Comment: Oh you saved my day, it just an Ads-block that block my API Thank you

Comment: Was facing a similar issue in Brave Browser while requesting through SwaggerUI for OAS3 spec. 
Disabled "Trackers & ads blocking" and "Fingerprinting blocking" and it worked.